# how to get two arrays from php using json,jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I want to build a graph in jqchart where i need to get two arrays

Now i want to perform operation as given below.Which is giving error ofcourse.

```
html
 $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "customer_coverage.php",
            data: {id:id},
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data21,data22) {

                initChart2(data21,data22);
            }
        });




        function initChart2(data21,data22) {
            $('#jqChart2').jqChart({


                series: [
                {
                            type: 'column',
                            title: 'no of days ',
                data:data21,

                        },
                {
                            type: 'column',
                            title: 'no of days ',
            data:data22,

                        },


                        ]
            });
        }
```

heres PHP code

```
  echo json_encode($arr1);
  echo json_encode($arr2);
```

So any one has idea of how to do it?

Comment: Why don't you Merge the 2 arrays and then Encode them as JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if you are able to produce two object arrays of json then you can try with this:

```
    var data21,data22; 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "customer_coverage.php",
        data: {id:id},
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function(i, item){
               data21 = item.data21;
               data22 = item.data22;
            });
            initChart2(data21,data22);
        }
    });
```

and i am supposing if you are able to produce this:

```
[
 {
    "data21": {
        .........
    },
    "data22": {
        ........
    }
 }
]
```

Answer (score 12):

no need to echo json encode two times....merge the array and send the data.......

```
echo json_encode(array('result1'=>$arr1,'result2'=>$arr2));
```

and get data by

```
initChart2(data.result1,data.result2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get multiple object like that. For a JSON object, you will need to have single object. So what you can do is, create a wrapper object put those two array inside it.

So basically, your php code will be:

```
<?php
$arr= array();
$arr['arr1'] = $arr1;
$arr['arr2'] = $arr2;

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

So now you will have single main array and so single JSON object.

On JS side, you will get single data. Little Modification will be

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "customer_coverage.php",
            data: {id:id},
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
            var data21=data['arr1'];
            var data22=data['arr2'];
                initChart2(data21,data22);
            }
        });
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine both array using `array_merge()`.

**Example**

```
$response = array();

$response = array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
echo json_encode($response);
```